# Create gene network from list of genes

Tags: networks

*This has also [been posted on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/312943/)*

I had an initial bipartite transcriptional regulatory network for bees. My idea is to create a similar network for termites so as to check if similar genes are hubs in both the networks (being that both are eusocial). For this purpose, I took the sequences of the genes in the honey bee GRN and did a BLAST to identify similar genes in the species of eusocial termite that I am interested in. The problem is that I am out of ideas on how to infer a network from the set of genes that I have.

I cannot use Genemania which can only be used for genes from specific species like humans, flies etc. I cannot use STRING because that uses protein sequences and the species I work with is also not on it. Most tools I found can be used for network creation only if the genes I have is from well studies species like mus musculus, drosophila etc.

Is there anyway in which I can create a network from the set of genes that I have?

I do not have interaction information. I have a network of genes from honey bees. I did a BLAST of the genes in that network and retrieved the gene names for the related genes that I got from a species of termites. I would like to create a gene network of that to check if the same genes form the hubs in both the networks.

The gene network in bees is a bipartite transcription regulatory network. I haven't checked the gene ontology of the termite genes but I would think that the genes should be having similar functions because they are BLAST results. There are around 2200 genes in the honey bee GRN and I could find approx 1000 genes from the BLAST and UNIPROT for termites. The honey bee GRN was generated experimentally by a different lab so I could not replicate what they did with ARACNE.

What do you suggest that I do to find similar genes then if a BLASTN is not sufficient information?